# is "koesou" some conjugation form of the verb koeru?

Tags: verbs

is "koesou" some conjugation form of the verb koeru? If so, which one? I can't find it in this conjugation table for japanese verbs [conjugation of japanese verb koeru](http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?JapaneseVerb=koeru&VerbClass=2&EnglishVerb=get%20fat,%20grow%20fertile%20/%20cross%20over,%20exceed)

Comment: Where did you see this form?  こす is the transitive "partner" of こえる.

Comment: A Rurouni Kenshin anime ending song,  "Heart of Sword"

Comment: transitivity in Japanese/English is the same thing than in spanish? does It means that the verb doesnt need a direct object to make a sentence with sense?

Comment: Why don't you look up the auxiliary 「そう（だ）」 in a dictionary　http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=sou `(Verb masu stem) + sou 
降りそう 
furisou 
= seems it will rain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for the lyrics to this song online, it appears to be こえ＋そう.  This 〜そう suffix means "seemingly" or "appears to be".  So it would mean "seems that I can cross over".

This 〜そう suffix attaches to the "stem" of a verb; that is, the part before the ます (there are technical names for these parts, but I won't get into that here).  So the 〜そう itself is not any conjugation of こえる, just the こえ〜 part.

> (こえる・こえます)　→　こえ〜　＋　〜そう　→　こえそう

Some other examples of this 〜そう

> - 雨が降りそう　→　Seems like it's going to rain
> - 本がテーブルから落ちそう　→　The book looks like it's gonna fall from/off the table
> - 食事がおいしそう　→　The food looks delicious (*you can attach this 〜そう to adjectives as well)