# what does the particle "de" means when it comes after a verb?

Tags: particle-で

As far as I know, the particle "de" is used to mean "at" or "in" , and also "by" , "with", "within" , "by means of" , and also "in total" , "for", "made of", but almost all times I've seen it, it comes after a noun. Then, what does it means when it comes after a verb?

For example in the sentences,

> Hitori de wa, tooi ashita wo
>
> Yoake no mama de, koesou de

Comment: You might want to provide some example sentences.

Comment: "when it comes after a **verb**" <- "Hitori" "~no mama" "~sou" are not verbs.

Comment: I was refering to the koesou. so, ~sou isnt part of a verb? What is it? I was just told in another topic that is a suffix that added to a verb means "it seems" , isnt so?

Comment: I guess that even when it translates to verbs in English ~sou can't be considered a verb in japanese?

Comment: The そう grammar turns the verb into a noun, which is why you always see some form of the copula after it. The で there is just the -て form of です.

Comment: @Blavius thanks, that clarify many things, but not everything. As  far as I know, the te form of a verb is used for requests, present progressive, connecting verbs and for asking permission. None of those uses seems to be aplying here. What does it mean the te form here exactly, why is it used?

Comment: Are the examples you gave complete sentences you found? If so, then I have no idea.

Comment: @blavius the first sentences of a song http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/kenshin/rksword.htm

Comment: @Pablo `~sou isnt part of a verb? What is it?` -> In the other thread I commented the そう(だ) is an auxiliary. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47264/is-koesou-some-conjugation-form-of-the-verb-koeru#comment84553_47264 「そうで」 here is its continuative form. So the で is part of the auxiliary そうだ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "Yoake no mama"? 夜明けのまま?  I can't get the context or meaning.

> koesou de
>   sounds like a short of 越えそうである.

So this is a part of lyrics of a song from TM revolution? You should have warned that since Japanese lyrics of a pop song often makes little sense even for the native speakers.

It seems the lyrics in non-romaji are as follows

独りでは遠い明日を  faraway tomorrow if it's only me,

夜明けのままで 越えそうで  it seems I pass it(tomorrow) while it's still dawn

Semantically that's all. I don't know what it is supposed to mean.